# C# - Add File as Resource to my Exe at Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, resources

I discovered that I can add Files (*.jpg) to my C# Resources in Visual Studio 2010. As far as I could read it should be possible to re-assemble the exe at runtime. I don't want to strip the exe apart by myself. I'm looking for C# routines that do that for me. Of course I don't want to modify the running exe but a copy of it. I could also live with it putting my source code inside my exe if I need to compile it again at runtime.

My goal:

1. Create copy of the running exe
2. Add a file to that copy **somehow**.
3. Close the running app
4. When user executes the copy it must have the file as resource inside. That's it.

---

**Edit:** C# compiler + Visual Studio 2010 is available at target system.

---

(I'm not programming a full installer, please don't say those bad words: "re-inventing" and "wheel", I know them by myself)

Comment: Why do you want to go these lengths just to embed files in your executable at *runtime*? I don't know how "programming a full installer" helps solve the problem, but it'll be significantly less effort and probably give you far fewer problems than the route you're suggesting.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're criticizing. I need to find out the best/easiest way to do *that thing above*. And stackoverflow has good answers as far as I know.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is something on the line of ildasm/ilasm. Not pleasant. But there may be an API to do it. Try looking at Mono, they have some great tooling and libraries to support their own compiler and IDE (MonoDevelop)

Comment: @mini-me What criticism? I'm trying to determine why you want to do it, in case there are better alternatives. At the very least, if your executable is installed to Program Files, then even if you modify a copy, out-of-the-box Windows security won't let you replace it unless you're running with an administrative token. What problem are you trying to solve by using the *specific mechanism* of modifying your deployed executable?

Comment: And if it *is* an installer, is there any reason not to consider something like [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)? Windows has a very mature setup engine which with a few exceptions is completely data-driven; no programming required.

Comment: @shambulator Windows Security is not a problem. I will not really distribute that program.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have a very hard time modifying your resource section in a way that won't break your executable without the benefit of a full compiler.

What you can do instead however is:

- Make a ZIP file (or other archive that contains all your files)
- Do a dumb-append of the contents of your ZIP file to the end of the executable
- Also append an int32 containing the length of your archive

You can read it by opening a `FileStream` for your own executable starting at `ExecutableLength - ZipLength - 4` and reading `ZipLength` bytes - which gives you just the zip portion which can be read using DotNetZip or another library.

Then when you want to modify the stored data:

- Rename your existing executable while running (which you can do)
- Read the first `ExecutableLength - ZipLength - 4` bytes of your executable and write them to a new file with the name your executable had originally before it was renamed.
- Create the new ZIP archive with your information in and append that.
- Append the int32 of the length of your new archive.
- Close the existing app and launch the new one.

Tadah - an executable that can modify its own stored resources.

Comment: I'm not sure if you say this wont help anyways but a full compiler is available.

Comment: If a full compiler is available then you can do weird things like including a copy of your own source code as a resource and rebuilding it. But this is far from a trivial thing to do and get it right - the solution I've given is far simpler and far less work.